# How to insert data in flex table in vertica using python 3

Tags: python, vertica

I am planning to save my unstructured data in flex tables in vertica. I am receiving lists of data (type of data in list may vary in every call) from client, i want to save this in vertica flex table using python 3.
How this can be done?

I found stuff on google, but there data is being loaded in flex table directly using csv or json file, not programmatically. I want to save it programmatically using python.

Thanks in advance for help -:)

Answer (score 2):

I found a way to copy/insert data from list to flex table (in vertica) using python:

## For list

```
# for python list
tempList = list()    
tempList.append('{ "_id" : "01011", "city" : "CHESTER-APL21", "loc" : [ -72.988761, 42.279421 ], "pop" : 1688, "state" : "MA" }')
tempList.append('{ "_id" : "01011", "city" : "CHESTER-APL21", "loc" : [ -72.988761, 42.279421 ], "pop" : 1688, "state" : "MA" }')
cur.copy( "COPY STG.unstruc_data FROM STDIN parser fjsonparser() ", ''.join(tempList))
connection.commit()
```

## For JSON

```
# for json file
with open("D:/SampleCSVFile_2kb/tweets.json", "rb") as fs:
    my_file = fs.read().decode('utf-8')
    cur.copy( "COPY STG.unstruc_data FROM STDIN parser fjsonparser()", my_file)
    connection.commit()
```

## For CSV

```
# for csv file
with open("D:/SampleCSVFile_2kb/SampleCSVFile_2kb.csv", "rb") as fs:
    my_file = fs.read().decode('utf-8','ignore')
    cur.copy( "COPY STG.unstruc_data FROM STDIN PARSER FDELIMITEDPARSER (delimiter=',', header='false') ", my_file) # buffer_size=65536
    connection.commit()
```

Answer (score 1):

Vertica-Python supports INSERT INTO.

Unless you need frequent and very small inserts, writing your data to a file and using COPY would most likely give better performance. If you do it through python, does that still not meet your idea of 'programmatically' ?

- https://github.com/uber/vertica-python
- https://pypi.python.org/pypi/vertica-python/

Comment: Thanks -:) it helps great, but i found another way too. please check my answer and let me know that is there any disadvantage of using this approach.

Comment: Yeah, "copy from stdin" will work great ! It might be considered poor practice because "copy" is intended for bulk load rather than frequent and small insertions, but unless you are in a case where resources and performance are a big concern, you're fine :)